# Using Disqus, is it possible to use the post likes in a post ranking algorithm?

Tags: wordpress, disqus

In a `wordpress` based online magazine, we're looking to implement a `post-ranking algorithm` based on `time of post` + `# of likes` from `DISQUS`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [Disqus API](http://disqus.com/api/docs/), it shouldn't be hard to code such a thing. You would be able to code your algorithm, and maybe also your own display of the comments, rather than Disqus handle the comment output.